# Force save files all browsers - not open in browser window

Tags: php, download

I'm after a simple solution to work in all browsers.

For specific file types, or targeted links via a class: how can I get them to simply force download in all major browsers.

I thought I found the perfect solution for apachce server - by adding this into the .htaccess.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Seems to work in Firefox and Safari, but not chrome or IE (have not tested anything else)

Can any one please help me with a solution on how to make links to force download the file, instead of opening in the browser, for ALL browsers.

I can't seem to find a full browser proof solution. Is it not possible?

Any links to tutorial or snippets would be awesome.

My website if PHP based so can make it work with PHP if posible.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Set the Content-Disposition header to "attachment", like so (in PHP):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

You can even propose a filename for the download (if it differs from the one given in the URL):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.ext');
```

If you want to do it directly in the Apache server, try this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf|csv|xls)">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

(you may add more extensions in the FilesMatch pattern)

Try to avoid using the application/octet-stream header if you can, that is, if Content-Disposition works without it. That's because some systems actually pay attention to the Content-Type and saves it together with the file. It's usually better for the user if their system can figure out the correct MIME type of the file.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I am adding this to my wordpress website. On my single-download.php template (this is where I want the force download to take place), I added your line into the template like this...
`<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage MyTheme
 */
get_header();
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
?>`
But doesn't seem to have an effect? Thanks

Comment: Make sure you run all header() calls BEFORE you output anything to the browser. If the get_header() function outputs anything, put your header() call before that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

add this to .htaccess (change pdf to whichever you want) -- this is currently working in all browsers I have tested (have not tested opera or safari)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$file` holds the path to your file heres a script I often use to do this:

```
$file = 'file.gif'; // example
$filesize=filesize($file);

if ($filesize > 0) {
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\";" );

readfile($file);
}
```

You do face problems with devices with no file structure (e.g. iPad/iPhone), but you can remove the Content-Disposition line to fix that.

Comment: Thank you, your answer seems really interesting. I reckon I could get this to work easy in a basic loop on wordpress, but my PHP knowledge is very basic. I'm trying to get this to work via galley short code... `do_shortcode('[gallery customgal="true"]');` which is generated by this custom gallery function... https://gist.github.com/2300437 - the **$fullsize_image** variable I want to force download, used on **line 108**. Any pointers would be much appreciated thanks. Josh